# Calculate running average

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a stream of data containing brand and consumption data;and am required to provide a real-time average consumption data on demand.
This is a high-volume ,low latency tick.
Typical last 5 ticks may be :

```
P&G 345.21
J&J 124.9
P&G 127.9
WAL 789
KMR 78.5
```

The possible options :
Populate data in a array/list - aggregate and return average on demand(not feasible considering volume)
Populate map with key and aggregate data on tick.Maintain a separate map with kep and tick count.Calculate and return average from map 1 and 2 on demand.
Is there a better data structure/algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: just to need calculate the running average of each brand?

Comment: yes  - but without knowing the existing count of entries for each brand

Comment: So, you don't have any count or brand now. But when get a count then immediately calc the mean of each brand?

Comment: The mean would be a on-demand request for a given brand.The idea is to figure out an approach that enables that to be calculated most efficiently - memory and processing wise

Comment: You need to keep sum and count for each brand. Combine them in one object/struct/record and then use a map brand -> (count, sum)

Comment: Seems like it'd be pretty easy to have a struct `{total,count}` in a map keyed by `key`. Update would be just adding to the total and incrementing the count. And if queries are much more frequent than updates, you could compute and the new average with every update.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, it is better to maintain an another map contains a dict of `{brand: (num, mean)}`, then when get new consumption `x`, you can update dict with

```
new_mean = mean + (x-mean)/(n+1)
n = n+1
```